# Print driver(windows unidrv) don't work after reboot

Tags: windows, registry, driver

It work well on Win10 for a few days, but one day I turn on my PC, find it broken.  
I search the registry, and find it in the follow key

> "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Environments\Windows
> x64\Drivers\Version-3\xxxPrinter"

Losing most of the property, only have "Depentent Files". I sure that it also have "Driver"="UNIDRV.DLL" and so on, like others, when it work.  
I can reinstall it to solve, but I'd like to know why it happen.
Anyone have idea? Thanks advance!

Comment: Probably security update-fix has broken your Print Spooler service. Try to undo changes by System Restore to working date. If it doesn't help ask [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I don't find security update recently, and I will ask Server Fault.   : )